# Scale Only One Image Down in Mobile View

Tags: css, html, mobile, responsive-design

I don't have very much html/css knowledge. I have the whole site golden for mobile/tablet view. I am running in to a problem with the navigation bar. When the screen is scaled down, the logo takes up the whole navigation bar and you can't see the links. All the other images scale down perfectly. I can't find where in the code to change this so the links either display below it or beside it- don't really care. I just want it to show.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header-wrapper" class="container">
    <div id="header" class="container">
        <div id="logo">
        <a href="/index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a></div>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/index.html" accesskey="1" `title="">Home</a>`</li>
                <li><a href="/ourteam.html" accesskey="2" title="">Our `Team</a></li>`
                <li><a href="/services.html" accesskey="4" `title="">Services</a></li>`
                <li><a href="/contact.html" accesskey="3" `title="">Contact</a></li>`
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="banner" class="container"><img src="images/img03.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

What would i add to the responsive css file to make it so that dang logo is not taking over the world?

css:

```
#wrapper
{
overflow: hidden;
padding-top: 100px;
}

.container
{
width: 1200px;
margin: 0px auto;
}

.clearfix
{
clear: both;
}

/** HEADER */

#header-wrapper
{
overflow: hidden;
height: 650px;
margin: 0px auto;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}

#header
{
overflow: hidden;
height: 75px;
background: url(images/img02.jpg) repeat-x left top;
}

/* Logo */

#logo

{
float: left;
width: 370px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #814059;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}

#logo h1
{
float: left;
padding: 5px 10px 0px 0px;
}

#logo h1 a
{
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-weight: 300;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#logo p

{
display: block;
padding: 25px 0px 0px 40px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 1.2em;
color: #E5C5C9;
}

#logo p a
{
color: #E5C5C9;
}

/* Menu */

#menu
{
float: right;
width: 750px;
padding: 20px 30px 0px 0px;
}

#menu ul
{
float: right;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
list-style: none;
line-height: normal;
}

#menu li
{
float: left;
}

#menu a
{
display: block;
margin-left: 1px;
padding: 7px 0px 7px 30px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #814059;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 300;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu a:hover, #menu .current_page_item a
{
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 5px;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

images of desktop vs mobile
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcjNf.jpg

Comment: can you include the relevant parts of your css? or even better a jsfiddle ?

Comment: I included part of the css. Sorry I am bad...I will go google what jsfiddle is now :P

Comment: did the answer by @kittykittybangbang work for you?

Comment: It didn't. I had to switch tasks at work so I couldn't respond. I I should have clarified that I have a meta tag which links a mobile view css file if the screen is smaller than a certain size. I keep changing and adding stuff to the mobile css file and seeing what works. 
I added what @kittykittybangbang wrote and nothing yet.

Comment: Okay. Actually with tinkering with @kittykittybangbang code, I was able to make it work. The only difference was i called it mobilelogo. Another obstacle was that the view wasn't updating on my phone... Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a @media query?

HTML:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header-wrapper" class="container">
        <div id="header" class="container">
          <div id="logo">
            <a href="/index.html"><img id="mobilelogo" src="images/logo.png" /></a></div>
            <div id="menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/index.html" accesskey="1" title="">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="/ourteam.html" accesskey="2" title="">Our Team</a></li>
              <li><a href="/services.html" accesskey="4" title="">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="/contact.html" accesskey="3" title="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="banner" class="container"><img src="images/img03.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
    @media (max-width:600px) {   // Or whatever screen width you want your breakpoint at
      #mobilelogo { height:60px; }    // Or whatever height is appropriate 
    }
```

Comment: thank you this worked. I changed it to mobilelogo and for whatever reason it worked. :)

Comment: Your change worked because I'm stupid -- you can only have one object assigned to an ID, and you'd already used #logo on the containing div, so the CSS would have ignored anything below it assigned to the #logo ID. I edited to reflect, for reference. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you want a mobile detect code if you aren't currently using one:

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};

if(isMobile.any()){
    // Mobile!
} else {
    // Not mobile
}
```

source: [A beautiful mind](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/)
You can then specific the image size with css class after the following code

```
    if(isMobile.any()){

}
```

It would go something like img.class or class.img { height:30%;width:30%